# Setting up Stripe Elements in PHP? Seems like my php code is not communicating properly with my JS

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments, stripe.js

I'm trying to set up Stripe Elements, and I'm quite new to this.

So, I included every bit of JS which was on the stripe docs about elements, I installed the Stripe API, and required it, also linked to the Stripe JS. This is how far I came, the PHP is on the top in the index.php file which also contains the HTML and js below the PHP.

PHP:

```
<?php 

require('C:/xampp2/htdocs/stripe/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/init.php');


// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("my_test_key");

// Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
// Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Charge the user's card:
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 1000,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "description" => "Example charge",
  "source" => $token,
));

?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="card-element">
      Credit or debit card
    </label>
    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>

    <!-- Used to display Element errors -->
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
  </div>

  <button>Submit Payment</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_wzqlUMA7qtsfN4RZnm9IOSkQ');
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
var style = {
  base: {
    // Add your base input styles here. For example:
    fontSize: '16px',
    lineHeight: '24px'
  }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>
card.mount('#card-element');

card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

// Create a token or display an error when the form is submitted.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the customer that there was an error
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});

on stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

  // Submit the form
  form.submit();
}
</script>
```

I'm kinda lost in this whole thing... Could you give me some idiotproof guidelines, please?

I also tried to change the action of the  to a custom .php file which contains the php code above, but same result. Seems like my php code cannot communicate with the javascript. Chrome devtool console shows no general javascript errors.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: open the network tab of your browser and check the `preserve log` checkbox. then see what happens.

Comment: I stumbled upon a good guide, I deleted everything and started over based on [this](https://medium.com/@Keithweaver_/using-stripe-with-php-c341fcc6b68b). Worked like a charm. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon [this guide](https://medium.com/@Keithweaver_/using-stripe-with-php-c341fcc6b68b), deleted everything I gathered from the stripe docs and started over based on the guide it worked like a charm.